# Can I move existing git repositories to another machine and add them to Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

One of my organization's servers running version control based on git stopped functioning a while ago and was replaced with a new machine running Ubuntu Server and GitLab Community Edition 9.2.5. I want to move the repositories from the old machine to the new GitLab interface, preferably without connecting the old machine to the network (using an external HD or similar). From what I gathered, physically moving the files should be straight-forward by simply copying the top-level folder containing `.git` to another location, retaining the complete version history, is that correct? After having moved all repos to the new machine, are they easily added to GitLab? What problems could arise?

Comment: Yes, just copy the whole directory over including the `.git` folder. No problems whatsoever. See the gitlab doc on how to create a repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [houtanb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5449925/houtanb) stated in the comments, copy over the whole directory making sure you copy over the `.git` directory.

If you do not wish to connect to the network as you said, [you will need to follow this guide on importing repositories into GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md).